# Add context menu for DPI settings

Tags: windows, settings, display, dpi

There are over 200 older programs that aren't displayed correctly and setting each .exe DPI awareness is a chore, I'm looking for a way to automate it from a batch process or a context menu that would possibly make it easier and quicker.
Is there a way DPI Aware settings on Windows 10 context menu, or somehow change the DPI settings to all the .exe/.lnk files in a single menu?

Comment: Should be easy enough. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've looked around and it doesn't seem someone came up with a solution for this.
What I've managed to find, though, was a PowerShell script which updates shortcuts in a bulk process, and that works really well, for instance, to change their original to new paths. But when it comes to DPI, I couldn't find any solution for bulk processing.
All shortcuts are sitting in a specific folder, pointing to .exes in their own folders.